# What does this margin symbol in the SSMS text editor mean?

Tags: ssms

While editing text in SSMS I mistakenly pressed a random keyboard combination, which I think began with <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, and found this diagonal arrow symbol appeared in the text margin where the breakpoints normally go:

[image: Diagonal upper-right pointing arrow in square box, in breakpoint margin]

Can anyone tell me what it means?

SQL Server 2016 13.0.15900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [the answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120139/strange-arrow-in-visual-studio-gutter-window), as soon as I remembered that SSMS is a 'special flavour' of the Visual Studio Shell.

In short, it's a Task List item, which is toggled on/off with `Ctrl-K`, `Ctrl-H`. Items can be displayed with the menu View/Task List.

Answer (score -1):

As per mssqltips documentation by @Arshad Ali [SQL Server Management Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2413/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-part-1-of-2/) Hit CTRL+K followed by CTRL+K again to toggle the bookmark on the line.

You can press CTRL+K followed by CTRL+N to move to the next bookmarked line from the current cursor location likewise to move back to the last bookmarked line you can hit CTRL+K followed CTRL+P from the current cursor location.

To clear all bookmarks from the current window you can hit CTRL+K followed by CTRL+L.

For further your ref [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts?view=sql-server-2017) , [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/ssms-the-query-window-keyboard-shortcuts/) and [here](http://allhotkeys.com/sql_server_management_studio_hotkeys.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not a bookmark, those have a different icon.